# Return multiple objects Angular 2 forms

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-components, angular2-formbuilder

I am new to angular 2. On uploading two or more documents, it is listed in the template. Each row of listed document has input slots for entering additional information. On submit, the values entered only in the last row of the documents list is returned as object. I want the values of all the rows entered in the document list to be returned. Below is my code

**Template**

```
<h1 class="separator">Manage Documents</h1>
<!-- in transit -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" style="display: none" (change)='onClickUploadDocument($event)' multiple>
<label for="uploadFile"  class="btn btn-primary">Upload Documents</label>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
<input type="button" value="Select Truck To Send Document" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectTruck">
</div>
</div>


<table cellpadding="4" class="grid" >
<thead><tr><th>Document Name</th><th>Document ID</th><th>Document Type</th><th>Source</th>
<th>Document Date</th><th>Trip ID</th><th>Notes</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>

<form [ngFormModel]="myform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myform.value)">
<tbody *ngFor="let file of files">
    <tr > 
    <td class="form-group" >{{file.name}}</td>
    <td class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"  ngControl="documentId" #documentId="ngForm"></td>
    <td class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="type" #type="ngForm"></td>
    <td class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="source" #source="ngForm"></td>
    <td class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control" ngControl="date" #date="ngForm"></td>
    <td class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="tripId" #tripId="ngForm"></td>
    <td class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="notes" #notes="ngForm"></td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <a (click)="remove(file)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 

        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
<!-- save button -->
<button type="submit" class="form-group" class="btn  btn-primary " >Save</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
 import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
    import {NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/common';
    import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
    import {FleetService} from '../../fleet/fleetControlPanel/fleetControlPanelService';
    import {DocumentManagementService} from './documentManagementService';

    @Component({
        selector: 'documentManagement',
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/features/documents/documentManagement/documentManagementTemplate.html',
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES ]
    })

    export class DocumentManagementComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

        myform: ControlGroup;
        file: any[];
        files: any[] = [];
        trucks: any[];
        errorMessage: any;
        checked: boolean ;

        // constructor to loop the products in product service file and disply in html
        constructor(private _fleetService: FleetService, private _documentManagementService: DocumentManagementService,
          _formBuilder:  FormBuilder){

            this.myform = _formBuilder.group({
                'documentId': [],
                'type': [],
                'source': [],
                'date': [],
                'tripId': [],
                'notes': []
            })
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {

        }

        ngOnChanges(): void {

        }

        onClickUploadDocument(event){
            console.log("clicked")
            let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;

        console.log("file: ",fileList);
        for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            var files = fileList[i];
             console.log("files are: ",files);
             this.files.push(files);

        } 
        }

        remove(file: any){

             console.log("delete file:..", file)

              var index = this.files.indexOf(file);
            this.files.splice(index, 1)
            console.log("total files in list:..", this.files)

         }

        onSubmit (documents: any) {
             console.log("returned objects are:..", documents)

        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me how to return the values entered for all the documents input slots. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row binds to the same control instance. You need to bind each to their own instance instead.

```
<tbody *ngFor="let file of files let i=index">
    <tr > 
    <td>{{file.name}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" ngControl="documentId{{i}}" #documentId="ngForm"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ngControl="type{{i}}" #type="ngForm"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ngControl="source{{i}}" #source="ngForm"></td>
    <td><input type="date" ngControl="date{{i}}" #date="ngForm"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ngControl="tripId{{i}}" #tripId="ngForm"></td>
    <td><input type="text"ngControl="notes{{i}}" #notes="ngForm"></td>
        <td>
            <a (click)="remove(file)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
       this.myform = _formBuilder.group({
       })

       this.files.forEach((f, i) => {
            this.myForm.addControl('documentId' + i, new Control()),
            this.myForm.addControl('type' + i, new Control()),
            this.myForm.addControl('source' + i, new Control()),
            this.myForm.addControl('date' + i, new Control()),
            this.myForm.addControl('tripId' + i, new Control()),
            this.myForm.addControl('notes' + i, new Control()),
       })
```

When `this.files` is updated (items added or removed) then `this.form` also needs to be updated.

You might consider wrapping each row in a component and use it as a control to make the code simpler. The component needs to implement `ControlValueAccessor` like shown for example in [Not getting updated value from model in events when implementing value accessor for custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259397/not-getting-updated-value-from-model-in-events-when-implementing-value-accessor/37259897#37259897)

Comment: Hi Günter, I'm getting this error after implementing your answer.
` ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find control 'documentId0'`

Comment: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find control 'documentId0'

Comment: Hard to tell. Maybe the way you built it the `*ngFor` runs before the controls are added to `myForm`. That would require a Plunker to reproduce and debug.

Comment: Yes I think that's what happening, I'll create a plunker so that you can get better idea

Comment: For some reason its not working in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/6WuPuLOZYTrX7q5bmOpx?p=preview

Comment: Try https://plnkr.co/edit/pTfxkRqXw5wOLRiA12dg?p=preview I guess there are still a few bits missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114557/discussion-between-gaurav-ram-and-gunter-zochbauer).